# CGAffineTransform on UICollectionViewCell not giving desired result

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, cgaffinetransform

I would like to make the currently selected cell in a UICollectionView "bulge" - it should be larger than the adjacent cells.

I tried doing:

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
```

this indeed makes the cell larger - but it clips to the UICollectionView frame and the overlap of the cell is incorrect - the cell will overlap on top of the cell left to it - but it will be "under" the cell right to it.

I would like for it to be similar to the "Magnifying" effect in OSX dock.

How can I change the "Z" of the cell and allow it not to clip to the boundaries of the UICollectionView?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> but it clips to the UICollectionView frame

Try to set clipToBounds to false for your collectionview. z-index is only for view's with the same superview.

> the cell will overlap on top of the cell left to it - but it will be
>   "under" the cell right to it.

zPosition should help here. you can set it like this

```
cell.layer.zPosition = 1; //standard is 0, don't forget to set it back to zero
```

if you are using xcode < 5 you need to include QuartCore

```
#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: All of the collectionview cells have the same superview - but on that issue I also added a separate question about that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901423/how-to-change-uicollectionviewlayoutattributes-of-one-cell . If you have an idea let me know. I'll try setting clipToBounds like you suggest. Thanks!