# How to change UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes of one cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I would like to change the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes attribute of one UICollectionViewCell without reloading or changing the layout object

I did

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

attributes.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
```

But this isn't propagating to the cell - how can this be done?

Comment: are you using UICollectionViewFlowLayout?

Comment: Yes - and the layout object is already determined - this is after the layout has completed

Comment: Have you tried `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:`?

Answer (score 1):

`-[UICollectionView layoutAttributesFor...]` methods return copies of the layout attributes. You can't modify the originals after the layout returns them.

Your best bet is to subclass the layout, and whenever you return the attributes for that item (either in layoutAttributesForItem or layoutAttributesForElementsInRect), return the modified attributes.

If the change is really really temporary, you can always manipulate the cell transform manually. The collection view doesn't really care -- it may reapply the attributes when the cell needs to be reloaded, though.